# schengan visa inquiry

Tags: visas

I am nishan and I am from Sri Lanka. At the moment  am working in Maldivies as a waiter.and my basic salary is 1000 us dollar plus fixed service charge as 350 dollars. I am working one year with this company and we ( my wife and my son) want to go to Europe  (Malta) for visit like 5 days.

My wife has fixed deposit worth 1.5 million srilankan rupees since 2014. We will pay our hotel reservations  and the airline tickets from that fixed deposit as well the rest from me.as well my wife has credit card. I have property and my own vehicle.

As well we have been to few countries like Singapore, Malaysia and Dubai. I have worked in Qatar. As well my wife studied in UK period of 2 years.but I have no sponsor  and Italian embassy doing the Malta visa in Srilanka.

Do you think this will OK for our visit  visa or do I need more.if any one can advise  me appreciate. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why there will be any problems.

Just attach everything you mentioned to your visa application (tickets, reservations, proof of wage for you & deposit balance for your wife) and fill the form correctly. Be sure to apply in advance (one month will be okay, two weeks might work)

Comment: What is the minimum  bank for be months  in euros

Comment: I mean bank balance  for 3 months in euroes

Comment: @jayalath "According to the information provided by the European Commission, a foreign national who wants to enter the territory of Malta, while applying for a Malta Visa it needs to attest owning 48€/day for the period of stay". So if you're coming for five days, it better be at least 250 euro equivalent, 300 euro to be on safe side of one-off days. For three months it should be more but still with 1.5 mln LKR you have nothing to worry about

Comment: Thank you.and my job is waiter  it's not an issue if am I right?

Comment: How can we booked train ticket or ferry ticket for in malta for embassy purpose

Comment: @jayalath I think you only need plane tickets if you're flying to Malta.

Comment: As I said am working  abroad and company will not deduct Epf or Etf  so in this do i have to produce an letter to the embassy?

Comment: @jayalath I have no idea what Epf or Etf is. If you're a resident of Maldives and work there you should probably be able to produce a letter from your employer.

Comment: Thanks alamar. So please help me with this question?utopian embassy will ask only 3 months statement  if produce 6 months that will be a problem or?what happens if I endorse  my 6 months bank balnce  in euroes?

Comment: @jayalath I don't think it would be a problem if you have sufficient funds there. I would probably avoid passing statement denominated in non-local and non-Euro currency tho.

Comment: I have a no any sponser  or any invitation letter from malta or person who lives in malta?the invitation  letter is really  important  to apply  for tourism  visa in malta

Comment: @jayalath I don't think you need invitation if you're purpose of travel is tourism and you have hotel booked.

Comment: Death alamar .if I submit  my 6 months bank statement and it has 3200 euro as my 6 months savings?do I have to give any bank certificate  if they asked?like when did  you account  opened  and the transaction been done like that?because malta visa  handling  by italy embassy  in srilanka?do you  think that they will ask from me?

Comment: @jayalath I don't know that, you better check their website for a list of documents.

Comment: Italy embassy  asking only 3 months bank statement. So wht  happens if I give 6 months

Comment: @jayalath Why don't you ask them by phone?